# In Clojure is an empty list a sequence of infinite nulls?

Tags: clojure

I am learning the concept of `sequence` and `nil` in Clojure. This was the result of a small experimentation.

```
1:6 user=> (first '())
nil
1:7 user=> (rest '())
()
1:8 user=> (first (rest '()))
nil
```

Does this mean that '() is actually a sequence of nils?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to test whether the "rest" of a collection is empty, use `next`.

```
user> (next '(foo bar))
(bar)
user> (next '())
nil
user> (doc next)
-------------------------
clojure.core/next
([coll])
  Returns a seq of the items after the first. Calls seq on its
  argument.  If there are no more items, returns nil.
```

"nil-punning" (treating an empty collection/seq and `nil` as the same thing) was removed last year in favor of fully-lazy sequences.  See [here](http://groups.google.com/group/clojure/tree/browse_frm/thread/088d9fdb5bcad36a/ac087a3c5447a43b) for a discussion leading up to this change.

Comment: When I write cond clauses to recur in a sequence, my first check is usually (empty? obj). Is that the correct way to recur in Clojure?

Comment: I think usually people test (seq obj) rather than `(empty? obj)`.

Comment: @BrianCarper Why? Is there a significant different between the two expressions?

Comment: @wrongusername - it's mostly convention, but (seq x) is shorter than the equivalent (not (empty? x))

Answer (score 4):

`first` and `rest` are functions that apply to a logical structure (a `seq`) and not on the linked cons structure of a list (as in other lisps).

> Clojure defines many algorithms in terms of sequences (seqs). A seq is a logical list, and unlike most Lisps where the list is represented by a concrete, 2-slot structure, Clojure uses the ISeq interface to allow many data structures to provide access to their elements as sequences.
>
> http://clojure.org/sequences

The behavior is a result of the definition of the function and not determined by the primitive structure of the data.

Answer (score 2):

**No** - an empty list is not the same as an infinite sequence of nils

This is relatively easy to show. Suppose we have:

```
(def infinite-nils (repeat nil)) ; an infinite lazy sequence of nils
(def empty-list    '())          ; an empty list
```

They have different numbers of elements:

```
(count infinite-nils) => doesn't terminate
(count empty-list)    => 0
```

Taking from them:

```
(take 10 infinite-nils)  => (nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil)
(take 10 empty-list)     => ()
```

If you call seq on them you get

```
(seq inifinite-nils) => sequence of infinite nils
(seq empty-list)     => nil
```

The confusion in the original can largely be resolved by understanding the following facts:

- **'() is a collection** (a persistent list), not a sequence. However it is sequential, so you can call [seq](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/seq) on it to convert it into sequence.
- **nil is the empty sequence** - so therefore `(seq '())` returns nil, as does `(seq (rest '()))`
- **[first](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/first) returns nil on an empty sequence** - hence why `(first (rest '()))` is nil.

Answer (score 1):

Also learning Clojure.

For empty  [sequences](http://clojure.org/sequences), `rest` returns a sequence for which `seq` returns `nil`.

That's why you get that behavior.

I assume this is to simplify recursing on sequences until they are empty, and probably other smartypants reasons...

Answer (score 0):

Technically **yes** though not in a useful way.

"Does the sequence that is created by calling (seq '()) have an infinite number of nulls?"
the answer is yes becase **the (rest) of an empty sequence is sill an empty sequence** which it's self can have a (rest)

This output is misleading by the way:

```
1:7 user=> (rest '())
()
```

the first '() in this is the **empty list**.
the secong () in this is the **empty sequence**.
sequences are printed the same as lists in the repl even though they are not the same.